# Replace sizer of a wxFrame in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets

I am writing a small Minesweeper game just to get familiar with wxWidgets (Windows, wxWidgets 3.1.4). The app can handle one game well, and now I would like to add the "new game" functionality. For the layout, I am using a `wxGridSizer`.

My first approach was to create a new `wxGridSizer` with the new fields in it, and just replace the current sizer with the new one. Even though I figured out how to reuse the old sizer (and it is probably also a better solution in general), I am kind of curious how can I replace the sizer properly.

I was able to simplify my problem to this:

```cpp
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
  #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
  virtual bool OnInit();
};
class MyFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
  MyFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size);

private:
  void OnExit(wxCommandEvent &event);
  void OnRefill(wxCommandEvent &event);
  wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

enum { ID_Refill = 1 };

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_MENU(ID_Refill, MyFrame::OnRefill)
EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, MyFrame::OnExit)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE() wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
  MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Hello World", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(300, 200));
  frame->Show(true);
  return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size)
  : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size) {
  wxMenu *menu = new wxMenu;
  menu->Append(ID_Refill, "&Refill...\tCtrl-R", "Creates new layout");
  wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
  menuBar->Append(menu, "&Menu");
  SetMenuBar(menuBar);
  wxGridSizer *sizer = new wxGridSizer(2, 2, 1, 1);
  SetSizer(sizer);

  for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    wxButton *button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, std::to_string(i), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    sizer->Add(button, wxALL, 0);
  }
}

void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent &) {
  Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnRefill(wxCommandEvent &) {
  Freeze();
  GetSizer()->Clear(true);
  wxGridSizer *sizer = new wxGridSizer(3, 3, 1, 1);
  SetSizer(sizer);
  for (auto i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    wxButton *button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, std::string("Refilled") + std::to_string(i), wxDefaultPosition,
                                    wxDefaultSize, 0);
    sizer->Add(button, wxALL, 0);
  }
  sizer->Layout();
  Thaw();
  Refresh();
}
```

The problem is after the `OnRefill` function the app only shows the first button (`Refilled0`), but not the rest of the buttons.

Before `OnRefill`:

[image: All buttons are shown]

After `OnRefill`:

[image: Only the first button is shown]

My question is how can I replace the sizer of `MyFrame` properly? Based on what I understood from the examples and the documentation, this should work, but I guess I am missing something.

Comment: Why do you have to replace anything?  The layout is the same, right?  You have the same grid of buttons in the same location.  All you need to change is the icon you display.  Right?

Comment: The size of the field can be changed also. I was able to solve my original issue by reusing the sizer, but I would like to know how a sizer can be properly replaced. I am interested in this because I don't see any reason why the code I pasted shouldn't work, therefore figuring out the issue would teach me something (which is desired during the learning process in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the sizer, you just need to make one small change to the `MyFrame::OnRefill` method.

Instead of calling `sizer->Layout();` simply call `Layout();`.  I'm not entirely sure why calling Layout for the sizer doesn't work.

The full method looks like this:

```
void MyFrame::OnRefill(wxCommandEvent &) {
  Freeze();
  GetSizer()->Clear(true);
  wxGridSizer *sizer = new wxGridSizer(3, 3, 1, 1);
  SetSizer(sizer);
  for (auto i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    wxButton *button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, std::string("Refilled") + std::to_string(i), wxDefaultPosition,
                                    wxDefaultSize, 0);
    sizer->Add(button, wxALL, 0);
  }
  Layout();
  Thaw();
  Refresh();
}
```